# K8S - Add ImagePullPolicy for with Certificate

Tags: kubernetes, ssh, cluster-computing

I use k8s with helm 3.

I want for test purpose, be able to access the current cluster of current machine.

When I run:

```
kubectl config view --raw
```

The output is like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    server: https://...
  name: cluster.local
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: cluster.local
    namespace: ...
    user: kubernetes-admin
  name: kubernetes-admin@cluster.local
current-context: kubernetes-admin@cluster.local
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: kubernetes-admin
  user:
    client-certificate-data: 
    ...
    client-key-data: 
    ....
```

For the output, I see that there that the configuration has server of name: `cluster.local`, and `current-context: kubernetes-admin@cluster.local`.

(Same as on ~/.kube/config file).

For users, there is one user called: `kubernetes-admin` with `client-certificate-data` value and `client-key-data` value. Also I see that there is a key:

What are `kubernetes-admin` and `client-certificate-data` stands for, and can I use them in `ImagePullSecret` section for K8S object of kind: Pod in container.

i.e:

I create a secret:

```
kubectl create secret my-secret ....
```

What to do in order to create a secret of the with certificate and not user + password?

and a pod (yaml file):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-pod
  labels:
    name: test-pod
    app: test-pod
spec:
  imagePullSecrets:
    - name: my-secret
  containers:
    - name: test-pod
      image: "my-image:1.0"
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
```

Can I create a secret use in `imagePullSecret` without provide user+password (this is no user and password - it's a certificate key / ssh).

For test purpose, I am using the current machine (before uploading to remote registry. Need to do some tests before that).

Thanks.

Comment: `imagePullSecret` should be something different from you kube config. from where do you pull the images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will contribute my knowledge as a solution for this issue.

There is no need to create a secret key for the current registry of local machine.

The current default cluster name is `cluster.local`.

All is needed to add an alias for the image, called: `cluster.local/my-image:tag` and use it in the yaml code.

That means, running:

```
docker tag my-image:1.0 cluster.local/myimage:1.0
```

and in yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-pod
  labels:
    name: test-pod
    app: test-pod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test-pod
      image: "cluster.local/my-image:1.0"
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
```

Comment: i'm confused by the way image name to be strongly associated with k8s cluster name. can you find any official document about this? and can you explain how you setup you k8s cluster and built the docker image?

Comment: When you enter each pod container , there is common file /etc/resolv.conf. In that file there are the domains for service. Domains are the suffix, and the cluster is the postfix. It is very common name, so I persume it is very basic on k8s infrastructure). See also in https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#:~dcm-bot-890c06f7dff54e2d9d35332364e37a4f Create service to hold subdomain, the name of pod is generaly the hostname, and the cluster is like the server name.

Comment: you're mixing docker registry with k8s service route i think. what you said is service name. but where are your docker(the docker tagged and push related) stored?

Comment: I meant that the default of domain+subdomain+cluster is very basic, and it is generally the pod_name.default.svc.cluster.local. When you declare a pod, you can replace that default by attributes: hostname replace the pod_name,  subdomain replaces the default, but you should declare a service with label name as same as default / subdomain name in pod (in pod_name.default...). That's the trick, otherwise, it won't work. K8s inject this into /etc/resolv.conf file in docker (which is like hosts file in windows). Cluster.local is also very basic.

Comment: where are your dockers stored? what registry do you use when `docker login`?

Comment: docker image inspect your_docker_id, and you find the mount volumes for the layers, which are actualy the files. For k8s the server is shown by kubectl config view, but you find there external registry or localhost, but you won't see the name cluster.local, which is a fixed name for local cluster. There is a file called .netrc - watch that. And for use you need to create a secret of docker-registry type and role+rolebinding to current account to access the remite regustryby docker login. K8s is actualy declare things in dockers.